# Could Telegram Bot has private chat?

Tags: node.js, telegram

I create a Bot and it able to send messages to my groups.
Now I'd like to create an interaction with it, like keyboard and so on.
I saw some bot that before use keyboard, and after the Human starts the chat in the same chat_id.

How Can I read and write like a human using Bot? Have I save the conversation (chat_id, user_id, messages) in a database and start a chat with API?

Answer (score -2):

You can send message via sendMessage method from telegram bot api ( [https://api.telegram.org/bot\*BOTTOKEN\*sendmessage](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5C*BOTTOKEN%5C*sendmessage))
and to receive you can create api to send a message to your handler, or use getUpdates method from telegram bot api

Comment: it isn't an answer to my question.